# Is there a way to check the u-boot config settings under u-boot shell?

Tags: config, u-boot

Is there a way to check the u-boot config settings under u-boot shell, similar to `/proc/config.gz` under Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Even if someone bothered to save a copy of the **.config** file with the **u-boot.bin** binary, it would not be a complete picture.  For many boards, not every CONFIG_* parameter has been transitioned from legacy configuration declarations in  **.h** files (using `#define CONFIG_xxx xyz`) to **Kconfig** menu entries.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for your comments. Given the reason you provided, I guess that the answer to the my question is “not yet”.